# Linear search in a sorted array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, linear-search

I want to make a program that searches linear in a sorted array and can output the different positions in which the searched item is found. At the moment my program only outputs the first position in which the search item is found, so here's an example from what what my program does right now:

```
Enter number of elements
5
Enter 5 integers
1
3
3
9
15
Enter value to find
3
3 is present at location 2.
```

Now the thing is that 3 is on location 2 and 3, and that's what i want to edit in the program but i don't know how to do it.

Here's the code of my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 class LinearSearchArray1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int c, n, search, array[];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
        n = in.nextInt(); 
        array = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        array[c] = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter value to find");
        search = in.nextInt();

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            if (array[c] == search)     /* Searching element is present */
            {
             System.out.println(search + " is present at location " + (c + 1) + ".");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c == n)  /* Searching element is absent */
        System.out.println(search + " is not present in array.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch` to find the first position. Then loop to find the others - they must be together in a sorted array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
System.out.println("Enter value to find");
search = in.nextInt();

boolean exists = false;

for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
{
  if (array[c] == search)     /* Searching element is present */
  {
     System.out.println(search + " is present at location " + (c + 1) + ".");
     exists = true;
  }
}

if (!exists)  /* Searching element is absent */
  System.out.println(search + " is not present in array.");
```

You need to delete the `break;` statement. Otherwise, as soon as the first value is found, the loop is broken, & the next matches would never be reached.

Comment: OMG it was actually that simple, just one problem left: i get "3 is not present in array." in the last line.

Comment: Actually, you need something like a flag. Check my edit.

Comment: @Sparta This will scan the whole array each time. A break on the next non-equal value would be better, since the array is sorted. (of course, a binary search would be preferred for larger arrays)

Comment: @Danny_ds you're right, totally missed the *sorted* fact.

Answer (score 1):

This code may work for you.

```
    int c = 0;

    while (c < array.length && array[c] < search)
    {
        cc++;
    }
    int first = c;
    while (c < array.length && array[c] == search) {
        c++;
    }
    int last = c;
```

Now elements between index "first" and "last" (including them) contain the searched number. So you basicly search for the first and the last element that are the same as you are looking for.
Example to write it to console:

```
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(search + " is present at location " + (i + 1) + ".");
    }
```

Comment: No, the `last` element does NOT contain the desired value. In fact, `last` will be outside the array if all elements are less than or equal to `search`. The code is correct (except for the `cc` instead of `c`), and in fact it is exactly what I would have used. However, after the code, what we know is that there are exactly `last-first` elements matching `search` (note that this could be zero), and those elements are between `first` (included) and `last` (excluded). The last `for` would work OK if the  `<=` were changed to a `<`. No iterations in that loop means `search` is not in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearch {
    /*
     * A binary search or half-interval search algorithm finds the position of a
     * specified value (the input "key") within a sorted array. Binary search
     * requires a sorted collection. Also, binary searching can only be applied
     * to a collection that allows random access (indexing).
     * 
     * Worst case performance: O(log n)
     * 
     * Best case performance: O(1)
     */

    public static int binSearch(int a[], int key) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = a.length - 1;

        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (key == a[mid]) {
                return mid;
            }
            if (key < a[mid]) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;

            }

        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        BinarySearch bi = new BinarySearch();
        int[] arr = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 };
        System.out.println("Please Key to be search");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        if (bi.binSearch(arr, input) != -1) {
            System.out.println(input + ": " + " Search found at "
                    + bi.binSearch(arr, input) + " " + "Position");
        } else {
            System.out.println(input + ": " + " Search Result not found ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ArrayList** to store the location:-

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class LinearSearchArray1 {

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int c, n, search, array[];
    boolean searchStatus=false;

    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
    n = in.nextInt(); 
    array = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        array[c] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter value to find");
    search = in.nextInt();
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        if (array[c] == search)     /* Searching element is present */
        {
         al.add(c+1);
         searchStatus=true;  
    }
}
if (searchStatus==false)  /* Searching element is absent */
    System.out.println(search + " is not present in array.");
else {
    System.out.print(search+ " is present in array at location ");
    for(Integer i:al) 
        System.out.print(i+",");
}
}
```

}